# How to kill a conditional boundary mutation concerning time

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, mutation-testing, pitest

I'm trying to test the following class

```
@Component
public class StreamListener {

  @Value("${kafkaMessageExpiration.maxExpirationInMilliseconds}")
  private long messageExpirationTime;

  public void handleMessage(Payment payment) {
    logIncomingDirectDepositPayment(payment);

    if (!isMessageExpired(payment.getLastPublishedDate())) {
      messageProcessor.processPayment(payment);
    }
  }

  private boolean isMessageExpired(OffsetDateTime lastPublishedDate) {
    return ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(lastPublishedDate.toInstant(), Instant.now()) > messageExpirationTime;
  }

}
```

I'm getting a "changed conditional boundary → SURVIVED" message on the condition in isMessageExpired().

I have the following tests which test when the difference is less than messageExpirationTime and when the difference is greater than messageExpirationTime.

```
@BeforeEach
void init() {
  ReflectionTestUtils.setField(streamListener, "messageExpirationTime", 60000);
}


@Test
void handleMessage() {
  Payment payment = TestObjectBuilder.createPayment();

  streamListener.handleMessage(incomingDirectDepositPayment);

  verify(messageProcessor).processDirectDepositPayment(incomingDirectDepositPayment);
}

@Test
void handleMessage_expired_message() {
  Payment payment = TestObjectBuilder.createPayment();
  payment.setLastPublishedDate(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).minusMinutes(10));

  streamListener.handleMessage(incomingDirectDepositPayment);

  verify(messageProcessor, never()).processDirectDepositPayment(incomingDirectDepositPayment);
}
```

I suspect the problem is that I don't have a test where the difference is equal. Assuming that is what I'm missing, I don't know how to get the difference to be equal. Any suggestions on how I can kill this mutation?

BTW, I'm using Java 11, JUnit 5 and PITest 1.6.3

Answer (score 1):

This issue is this

```
Instant.now()
```

If time is one of the inputs your code depends on you need to make that explicit so you can control it.

This is normally achieved by injecting a `java.util.Clock` (held as a field, injected via the constructor). Your call to `Instant.now()` can then be replaced with `clock.instant()` and the code becomes properly unit testable.